# Browse YouTube with Google Chrome in Mac results in transparent video window

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome can't play YouTube video since few days before.

- Google Chrome version: 12.0.742.100
- Flash player version: 10.3.181.26
- Mac OSX version: 10.6.7
- Extension installed: Tempermonkey , XML Tree

Symptoms:

- When YouTube video is played, audio only
- video area is transparent, revealing the contents behind Chrome
- when right click on the video area, the contents behind Chrome are clicked
- When Firefox 5 views YouTube , Flash Player crashes
- When Safari 5 views YouTube , it hangs (needs Force Quit)
- Since it happens, VLC cannot play video anymore (sound only)
- QuickTime works fine
- Issue only happens in YouTube site
- also happens in Incognito mode

I wonder if YouTube uses HTML5 player for Chrome or not.

Comment: YouTube only uses the HTML5 player if you opt-into it.

Comment: @Mark: how to opt-in / out ?

Comment: Go [here](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

Comment: after I joined the HTML5 Trial and view a video, the whole page become transparent !!!

Comment: Whoops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have:

- The same version of Chrome
- The same version of Flash
- Mac OSX 10.6.8

I do not see Tempermonkey available in Google Extensions, but I install XML Tree and was not able to repro the problem.

I do see something called Tampermonkey, and that could definitely be causing your problem. I would try uninstalling it and re-starting Chrome to check.  If so, you have probably installed a script that has mucked up youtube.  Go through your installed scripts and remove them until you find your problem.

Edit: It could be a quicktime problem if you are seeing a problem with HTML5 videos also.

Comment: i'll try to re-install QuickTime to see if the problem persists. Thanks.